# How to use map function to collect an array of string?

Tags: rust

I want to convert an array of `[Decimal; 12]` into `[String; 12]`

I use [decimal module](https://docs.rs/rust_decimal/latest/rust_decimal/) to store numbers, but I need to convert it into string for display

```
fn rows_to_string(arr: [Decimal; 12]) -> [String; 12] {
    arr.into_iter().map(|row| row.to_string()).collect()
}
```

But this give me error:

```
error: an array of type `[std::string::String; 12]` cannot be built directly from an iterator
label: try collecting into a `Vec<std::string::String>`, then using `.try_into()`
note: required by a bound in `collect`
label: try collecting into a `Vec<std::string::String>`, then using `.try_into()`
```

if I follow the error instruction and change the code above into:

```
fn rows_to_string(arr: [Decimal; 12]) -> [String; 12] {
    arr.into_iter()
        .map(|row| row.to_string())
        .collect::<Vec<String>>()
}
```

Now, the function returns a vector `Vec<String>`, instead of `[String; 12]`

Comment: TLDR  the duplicate: use `.collect::<Vec<String>>().try_into()` (which is also what the compiler suggests).

Comment: The iterator doesn't keep track of the length. So, collecting into a fixed size directly is (AFAIK) not possible (even though *you* know it will always have 12 elements). What you could do, is `.collect` into a `Vec`, then convert it back into an array using `.try_into().unwrap()` (safe to unwrap, you know it has the right size).

Comment: OK. it works now. thanks for @FZs to explain why